# Is it possible to filter an array of select values from a form?

Tags: php

Say I have this form:

```
<form method="post">
  <select name="s[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="12345678">One</option>
    <option value="a7e6b65e">Two</option>
    <option value="ad2445f7">Three</option>
    <option value="998d64fe">Four</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted, can I use one of the [Filters functions](http://www.php.net/manual/ref.filter.php) to make sure the data is OK?  My first thought was `filter_input_array`, but I don't think that's it.

The only way I see, is to first check if I have an array, then cycle through the values:

```
$s_clean = array();
if (isset($_POST['s']) && is_array($_POST['s'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['s'] as $o) {
    $s_clean[] = filter_var($o, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^[0-9a-f]{8}$/')));
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Bram and b7kich, who each gave me part of the solution I'll use since it doesn't appear that Filters functions can help here.

The idea to have a list of possible value is great (doh!) and by looking at the `array_*` functions I found `array_intersect`, which filters out any non 'valid' values.

```
$valid = array('12345678','a7e6b65e','ad24d5f7','998d64fe');
if (!isset($_POST['s']) || !($s = $_POST['s']) || !is_array($s))
  $s_clean = array();
else 
  $s_clean = array_intersect($s, $valid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should already have al possible option values available in an array.
Just validate if the options retrieved at the post are defined in the array.

```
if (!in_array($o, $options)) {
    //Throw some validation error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see array_filter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

In PHP 5.4 you could do

```
$s=$_POST['s']; 
if (!$s || !is_array($s) 
   $s=array();
else 
   $s=array_filter($s, function ($value)  { return preg_match('/regex/',$value); });
```